# Generating unique binomial random variates

Tags: binomial-distribution, random-variable

Let the set $\{X\}$ be a collection of $n$ iid random samples of $X_i \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(m,p)$. Define $\{Y\}$ to be the set of unique values of $\{X\}$. Is there an efficient method for generating a random sample of $\{Y\}$ directly, without having to construct $\{X\}$ and finding the uniques?

Example: For $m=64$,  $p=1/2$, and $n=10$ we could have

$X=\{28, 34, 32, 35, 29, 32, 36, 34, 30, 30\}$

$Y=\{28, 34, 32, 35, 29, 36, 30\}$

For small $n$ finding the uniques of $\{X\}$ is trivial, but if $n=10^9$ (say) we have $|X|=10^9$ but $E[|Y|]=47.05$ as

$$E[|Y|] = \sum_{i=0}^m 1- {\left(1 - p^m_i \right)}^n$$

where $p^m_i$ is the Binomial probability mass function

Comment: I think this might be a possible solution? : Construct a random multinomial distribution allocating n items across m+1 bins according to the Binomial distribution. Then, sample without replacement across the indices of the bins with the multinomial variate being their respective weights.

Comment: How would that work in the example, exactly? For instance, the chance associated with the $0$ bin is $2^{-64},$ so how many of the $10^9$ items would you put in that bin? Note that $10^9\times 2^{-64}$ is tiny.

Comment: @whuber Correct. Very small chance, which is the same as almost never observing a zero heads out of 64 flips (if p=1/2), even after 10^9 trials.

Example: 

Random multinomial allocation of 10^9 with distribution of the PMF of binomial (64,1/2):

Comment: {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 36, 156, 669, 2633, 8642, 26495, 75110, 194418, 472908, 1063872, 2227503, 4354179, 7949764, 13586459, 21740516, 32605678, 45903861, 60652519, 75278465, 87831395, 96346758, 99348834, 96328868, 87835184, 75296528, 60645909, 45889846, 32617139, 21741070, 13591220, 7954290, 4354515, 2229168, 1063417, 472384, 195910, 74972, 26587, 8513, 2665, 685, 189, 47, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

(i.e. 13 heads out of 64 flips appeared 669 times out of the 10^9)

Comment: The indices are {0,1,...,64} with weights given above. Only 47 of them have non-zero weights. We sample, without replacement, producing a vector of length 47

{32, 33, 27, 34, 31, 40, 35, 29, 39, 19, 30, 41, 38, 25, 36, 37, 26, 28, 43, 44, 23, 21, 42, 46, 24, 22, 50, 20, 45, 17, 18, 49, 14, 47, 15, 16, 48, 13, 51, 52, 53, 12, 11, 10, 54, 9, 55}

Comment: 1. You might be able to proceed by generating a single value from the binomial, then compute the conditional distribution with that generated value removed (as a multinomial), then generate a single value from that distribution, and proceed recursively, recomputing the conditional distribution without any previous values and generating a value from it.  2. If the "compute the conditional distribution with the just-generated value removed" step is too slow (likely if the original binomial has a very large $n$), then perhaps use a form of adaptive rejection sampling; ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... generate new values until you get say a duplicate  (or perhaps several) of a previous one and then compute the conditional distribution removing all the values generated (since the last such removal) from the distribution. (With such approaches it's important to think hard about avoiding unnecessary computations along the way)

Comment: @Glen For values of $n$ and $m$ that aren't *too* extreme, your first suggestion works well.  (I was testing it out as you were making that comment!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have the right idea: take a *single* sample from the multinomial distribution defined by the vector of $m+1$ Binomial$(m,p)$ probabilities and the integer $n.$

In general, you can obtain a sample from a multinomial distribution of size $n$ with $k$ probabilities $p_1,p_2, \ldots, p_k$ recursively : draw a Binomial$(n,p_1)$ value $Y_1$ to determine the count in the first box and then repeat with the probability vector $(p_2,p_3,\ldots,p_k)$ (renormalized to sum to unity) and the new size $n = n - Y_1.$

**Eliminating the tail recursion gives the following reasonably efficient algorithm** to draw one such multinomial variate:

```
s <- p[1] + p[2] + ... + p[k]
For i from 1 to k:
    p[i] <- p[i] / s
    x[i] <- random binomial draw of size n and probability p[i]
    n <- n - x[i]
    s <- s * (1 - p[i])
Return x
```

Its inputs are (1) the value of $n$ and (2) a possibly unnormalized probability vector $p$ of length $k.$  The running variables are $n,$ the updated size, and $s,$ the value needed to normalize the remaining probabilities.  By updating $s$ we have to adjust each component of $p$ just once, making this a $O(k)$ algorithm.

Note that with $n \gt 52$ or so, some of the binomial probabilities $p_i$ will be so small that $1-p_i = 1$ in double precision floating point arithmetic. I don't think this causes much harm, though, because the relative error it creates is tiny.  But once $m$ exceeds $1024$ (approximately), double-precision arithmetic will treat the tiniest probabilities (which get as low as $2^{-m}$) as true zeros.  Thus, this algorithm requires more precision when $n 2^{-m}$ is a large enough chance to affect the number of unique values.

**Here is the result of $5000$ iterations of this algorithm:**

[image: Figure]

The mean is $47.053 \pm 0.012.$

---

This is the `R` code I used to generate the figure.

```R
rmult <- function(n, prob) {
  k <- length(prob)
  x <- rep(as.integer(0), k)
  s <- sum(prob)
  for (i in 1:k) {
    prob[i] <- prob[i] / s
    #
    # `rbinom` fails when n * prob[i] is too large.  Replace it with a Normal
    # approximation in such cases.
    #
    if (n * prob[i] > 1e8) {
      x[i] <- max(0, min(n, round(rnorm(1, n * prob[i], sqrt(n * prob[i] * (1-prob[i]))))))
    } else {
      x[i] <- rbinom(1, n, prob[i])
    }
    if (!is.na(x[i])) n <- n - x[i]
    s <- s * (1 - prob[i])
  }
  x
}

n <- 64
p <- dbinom(0:n, n, 1/2)

set.seed(17)
x <- replicate(5e3, sum(rmult(1e9, prob=p) > 0))
plot(table(x)/length(x), xlab="# Unique", ylab="Frequency",
     main=paste0(length(x), " Simulated Experiments"))

(round(c(Mean=mean(x), SE=sd(x) / sqrt(length(x))), 3))
```

Comment: Tried it with smaller values so can compare with direct simulation

`n <- 8;  
x <- replicate(5e3, sum(rmult(10, prob=p) > 0)); `

Produces mean(x)=3.39, but the expected value of the number of unique values of Binomial(8,1/2) across 10 samples is 4.78.

Comment: I am so sorry--there was a typographical error in the code, which I also copied into the algorithm: `s` needs to be updated by *multiplying* it by the factor `1 - p[i]` rather than dividing it.  I have updated the algorithm, the code, and the figure accordingly.  The corrected code produces a mean of $4.817\pm0.13$ in your test case, consistent with the expected value. When run with one hundred times as many simulated datasets the mean is $4.7812\pm0.0013.$

Comment: Thank you. The corrected version works perfectly now. Accepted the answer.